# c++ float дробная часть

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    float gallons, liters;
    cout << "Inter gallons:";
        cin >> gallons;
        liters = gallons * 3,78541;
        cout << "litters: " << liters;
    return 0;
}
```

Как вывести число с дробной частью, потому что сейчас при вводе 1 просто округляется до 3? И соответственно при вводе 2 выводит 6.

Comment: 3,78541 а у вас запятая там почему стоит вместо точки?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Использовать точку вместо запятой -

```
3.78541
```

Так уж принято в этом языке :)

Предупреждая возможный вопрос - запятая - это отдельный оператор, так что ошибки как таковой у вас нет. Есть (бессмысленная в данном контексте) инструкция 78541.

Answer (score 7):

В С++/С (как и практически во всех остальных ЯП) дробная часть числа с плавающей точкой(!) (floating point number) отделяется от целой ТОЧКОЙ, а не запятой. Учитывая, что существует оператор "запятая" (comma operator), Ваше выражение имеет вид:

```
(liters = gallons * 3), 78541;
```

Нужно написать:

```
liters = gallons * 3.78541;
```